# SQL Stored Procedure to Scala/Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working on transferring an archaic system, written mostly in **SQL stored procedures, to Scala to run on Spark**. The stored procedures are batch jobs run once per day/week/moth/year, on "Request" objects, that can take hours to run.

Do to several reasons, we are changing the system to a streaming model (Spark Streaming).

In the old system, a lot of the logic is performed with join statements, where a big batch of Requests is joined with many tables.

One solutions is to essentially take the same SQl code and port it into Spark SQL statements which will then run on "micro-batches" of Requests. However, this means we still are performing lots of join statements which, I have heard, are  inefficient in Spark SQL.

A second idea I have is to take the business logic, and write the code as if we only had to **process a single Request** (i.e. if you have 10 applications, instead of processing all of them with joins, you would program as though you were handling a single request). I would then take the micro-batch of Requests and map them through the logic processing (i.e. Requests.map(r => RequestLogic.execute(r))).

Something like the following example code:

```
case class Request(id: Int, typeId: Int, value: Long)

def CreateStreamingContext(sparkConf: SparkConf, streamDuration: Duration,
                             storageLevel: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY): StreamingContext = {

    sparkConf.set(SparkArgumentKeys.MaxCores, (partitionCount * 2).toString)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, streamDuration)
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)

    val stream = EventHubsUtils.createUnionStream(ssc, hubParams, storageLevel)
    stream.checkpoint(streamDuration)

    stream.map(x => Request(x(1), x(2), x(3)))
      .map(r => RequestLogic.execute(r))

    ssc
}
```

I am trying to figure out:

> 1) Which one would scale better.
>   2) What are the pros/cons of each.

I am new to Scala/Spark and trying to figure out the best way. I am not sure if this is enough information, I will try and give more detail if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, and the answer depends on the shape of your data. I would like to assume two cases:

- First, you have a lot of `Request` data and you want to join them to comparably small amount of master data.
- Second, the amount of data for `Request` data and the data to join to are equally big and exceed RAM of your cluster.

In the first case you can advice Spark (in principle it should also be able to determine automatically) to use something called [`BroadcastHashJoin`](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5458351705459939/831709535720258/5521341683971298/latest.html). The strategy is to broadcast the small table to each Spark worker, and join it with each element in the larger RDD. There will be more than 2 non-empty partitions, so Spark would run faster with more than two worker nodes. In contract the `ShuffleHashJoin` would take all the rows in and shuffle them with the key. There will only be 2 non-empty partitions for the whole table, and adding more worker nodes to the job would not help. So being able to do a `BroadcastHashJoin` ensures scalability with the least amount of effort. For more details the the linked notebook from DataBricks.

In the second case your strategy is not a bad idea. We had good experience with preprocessing the data to join in an external KV-Store like [RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org/) or [AWS DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/de/documentation/dynamodb/) then doing the lookup and join in a streaming fashion. But while being able to scale this procedure even on a small cluster to really massive datasets, the performance and effort is much higher, than the pure Spark in-memory approach.